# How to block new incoming messages on a Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

As mentioned in the title, is there a way to block new incoming new messages on a Kafka topic? I would like to still be able to read from it, but I don't want it to receive any new messages anymore.

I'm expecting here that existing behaviours on other Kafka topics remain unaffected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to setup ACL policies on your entire Kafka cluster, then deny produce requests or set quotas to disallow production into the topic from any authenticated and authorized client.

Without authorization (by using PLAINTEXT listeners), you cannot prevent any client from producing into a topic.